# Extract 2 int value inside a string C#?

Tags: c#, windows, string, visual-studio, int

I have this code:

```
int[,] matSong;
int nNote = 0;

OpenFileDialog Of = new OpenFileDialog();
Of.ShowDialog();

StreamReader fp = new StreamReader(Of.FileName);
nNote = Convert.ToInt32(fp.ReadLine());

matSong = new int[2, nNote];

int i = 0;
string buffer = fp.ReadLine();

while (buffer != null)
{
    int.TryParse(buffer, out matSong[0, i]);
    int.TryParse(buffer, out matSong[1, i]);
    MessageBox.Show(buffer);
    buffer = fp.ReadLine();
    i++;
}
```

The strings that I read from file are like this "123 400" or "1234 500" or "1234 1000".

The solution int.Tryparse() doesn't work.

How can I save the 2 numbers into my matrix ?

The file.txt is like this:

```
4
123 400
234 500
354 700
233 500
```

if you have another solution to put the numbers into my matrix I would be gratefull.

I'm apologise for my english and I hope you can undestand my problem.

Thankyou vary much for you help.

Matteo Angella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your strings:

```
while (buffer != null)
{
    var words = buffer.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int.TryParse(words[0], out matSong[0, i]);
    int.TryParse(words[1], out matSong[1, i]);
    buffer = fp.ReadLine();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the file line by line you should read it word by word:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Of.FileName);
string[] words = text.Split(' ');
```

You could try it with

```
string[] words = fp.ReadToEnd().Split(' ');
```

But as mentioned in the comments it will not interpret the line breaks correctly.

Comment: This won't work quite right, either - `ReadToEnd()` with the split will cause the line break to be one word, ie: `{"4\n123", "400\n234", "500\n354", ...`